# Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed after importing OSM File with Java and neo4j spatial

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gis, openstreetmap, neo4j-spatial

I am new to neo4j and neo4j spatial. I want to import an OSM-File which i exported from https://www.openstreetmap.org/export. For this i use the following code. All examples i could found does not work for me or was incomplete. So i try to get a version which compiles:

```
   try {
        OSMImporter importer = new OSMImporter("osmGauKlein");
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
        config.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "90M" );
        config.put("dump_configuration", "true");
        config.put("use_memory_mapped_buffers", "true");


        BatchInserter batchInserter = BatchInserters.inserter(dbf, config); 
        importer.importFile(batchInserter, "osm/map.osm", false);
        batchInserter.shutdown();

        GraphDatabaseService dbs = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(dbf);      
        importer.reIndex(dbs, 10000);
        dbs.shutdown();

    } catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After doing this i can see the nodes in the neo4j browser. But after importing some of the spatial procedures doesn't work anymore. For example:

```
call spatial.layers
```

It just returns this error:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `spatial.layers`: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/filter/text/cql2/CQLException
```

Some other procedures are still working like

```
call spatial.layerTypes
```

What is the problem here?
When trying to import the OSM directly with cyper i used:

```
call spatial.importOSM("C:/Users/Steffen/workspaceEclipse/NDBS Neo4J/osm/map.osm")
```

But this leads to an other error

```
Failed to invoke procedure `spatial.importOSM`: Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: More than one element in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy$1@7ce40edf. First element is 'Node[50]' and the second element is 'Node[1206]'
```

Some infos:
Windows 10 64 bit,
neo4j 3.2.1,
neo4j-spatial-0.24-neo4j-3.1.1-server-plugin